# Difference between destructors in my class

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm implementing a simplified unique pointer. Everything was pretty clear, but I wonder about the destructor in my class.

Should it be `~unique_pointer(){obj->~T();}` or `~unique_pointer(){delete obj}`?

I really don't see a difference between these. Can you explain how they work?

Below is the whole class:

```cpp
template<class T>
class unique_pointer{
private:
    T*obj;
public:
    unique_pointer(const T* obj):obj{obj}{}
    ~unique_pointer(){obj->~T();}
    
    T operator*() const { return *obj; }
    T* operator->() const { return obj; }

    T* release(){
        T* temp = obj;
        obj = 0;
        return obj;
    }
};
```

Comment: Calling the destructor (`obj->~T();`) is something you do after having used placement new. I don't see that in your code so, you should most probably _not_ call the destructor. Use `delete`. Calling the destructor doesn't free the memory allocated, `delete` does.

Comment: If you don't know that you need to manually invoke a destructor (which only destroys the object, but does not deallocate it in any form), then you don't need to do it, and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: The paring is `new`/`delete`, `new[]`/`delete[]`, placement new/explicit destructor call(`obj->~T()`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It should be ~unique_pointer(){obj->~T();} or ~unique_pointer(){delete obj}. I really don't see difference between each other.

`obj->~T()` destroys the pointed object. If the object is stored in dynamic memory, then **the memory is not dealloated**. If nothing else deallocates the memory, then the memory is leaked. Given that the point of a unique pointer is to manage dynamic allocation, doing this would be rather pointless.

`delete obj` If `obj` was created with allocating `new`, then this destroys the object and frees the deallocation. Otherwise the behaviour of the program is undefined. This is what `std::default_delete`, the default deleter of `std::unique_ptr`, does (unless the template type argument is `T[]` in which case it calls `delete[]` instead).

Some simple rules of thumb that apply to most cases:

- If you new, then delete
- Delete only if you newed
- Never delete more than once
- If you newed an array, then delete[] instead
- Don't use new nor delete except in implementation of a smart pointer or similar low level memory management class
- If you malloc, then free
- Never free more than once
- Don't malloc
- If you placement new, then call destructor explicitly
- Don't placement new unless you know what you're doing

---

P.S. Your `release` doesn't seem to make sense, as it doesn't release `obj`, has an unused variable `temp`, and uses some undeclared `val`.

Furthermore, it is copyable and have undefined behaviour if copied or moved. A unique pointer shouldn't be copyable, and needs a custom definition for move.